# How can I read a resource in a simple class (no inject)?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have some worker classes which by definition have no injected services. I don't want to pass them down in the constructor.

Is there some way to access the resources directly? It's possible in WinForms so I'm guessing there should be a way in ASP.NET Core.

For example, in the following class I want to get the text "Hosting", "Interested", & "Attending" from the resources.resx. I do not want to have to pass (inject) a resource service to the class constructor.

```
public class SignupModel
{
    private readonly ExIdentityUser _identityUser;
    private readonly Signup _signup;

    public string UserName => _signup.User.Name;

    public string UserEmail => _identityUser.Email!;

    public string UserPhoneFormatted => _identityUser.FormattedPhoneNumber!;

    public string UserPhoneE164 => _identityUser.PhoneNumber!;

    public string Commitment { get; }

    public SignupModel(Effort parent, Signup signup, List<ExIdentityUser> listIdentityUsers)
    {

        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(signup.User);
        var @event = parent as Event;
        if (@event != null)
            ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(@event.Hosts, nameof(@event.Hosts));

        _identityUser = listIdentityUsers.First(user => user.Id == signup.User.IdentityUsersId);
        _signup = signup;
        if (@event != null && @event.Hosts!.Any(host => host.Id == _signup.User.Id))
        {
            Trap.Break();
            Commitment = "Hosting";
        }
        else
            Commitment = signup.Commitment == Signup.Mode.Interested ? "Interested" : "Attending";
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an Example?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis - done. TIA